# How can I change the notification level when pushing a bundle containing multiple cards?

Tags: google-mirror-api

A handful of apps such as The New York Times push a bundle containing two or more items to a user's timeline and manage to only play the default "jingle" notification sound once.

The Mirror API currently offers a parameter for `notification.level`, however the documentation only displays a single available parameter: `DEFAULT`.

How can I push multiple cards to a user but only play the notification sound once? I'd ideally like to only have the notification sound tied to the bundle cover item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the sound on the bundle cover item - just set it for that only. You can leave the `notification` field empty or null for the cards you don't want to play sound for.

Comment: Wow, that was obvious. I assumed that not defining the notification field would default to `DEFAULT`. However, I guess leaving it blank entirely disables the audible notification. Thanks!